# RXJS Observable remove pipe operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a problem where I want to remove/add any previous added operators of an observable.

I am given the following observable which I cannot change:

```
let objects$ = of([{
      category: 1,
      name: 'Some1'
    }, {
      category: 2,
      name: 'Some2'
    }]).pipe(
      map(o => o.filter(b => b.category === 2))
    )
    objects$.subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

This outputs: `{category: 2,name: 'Some2'}` as expected.

Now I want to change the value of the filter to `b.category === 1` to output `{category: 1,name: 'Some1'}`.

If I do the following:

```
objects$.pipe(
      map(o => o.filter(b => b.category === 1))
    )
    objects$.subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

I still get `{category: 2,name: 'Some2'}`.

If I do:

```
objects$ = objects$.pipe(
      map(o => o.filter(b => b.category === 1))
    )
    objects$.subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

I get `[]` because the output of the observable does not have category 1 anymore.

The question I have is how do I remove the `.pipe()` from the original observable to add a new one ?

Comment: If what you are getting is already the filtered observable, you can not do anything. If it;s possible, objects$ should be declared without the filter, just of(...). then it can be used in multiple places depending upon the use case.

Comment: Why you can't change it ? If you use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) then your source observable is mutated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can't remove operators

By using `pipe` e.g. calling `observable$.pipe( map(..) )` you're not really adding something to the `observable$` that can be taken away later on, even if the phrase `add operator X to your observable` is quiet often used.

> A pipeable Operator is a function that takes an Observable as its input
>   and returns another Observable. It is a **pure operation**: the previous
>   Observable stays unmodified

```ts
const o1$ = of('1');
const o2$ = o1$.pipe(
  map(x => x + '2'),
  map(x => x + '3')
);
```

is equivalent to

```ts
const o1$ = of('1');
const o2$ = map(x => x + '3')(
  map(x => x + '2')(
    o1$
  )
);
```

You're basically chaining pure function calls with your original Observable `o1$` as input and some other Observable as output. `o1$` won't be changed so you have to assign the returned value to a variable (`o2$`) to use later on or use it directly to have any effect.

In the example above you could reuse `o1$` and create a different Observable than `o2$` by using different operators on `o1$`. You can't however remove the function calls that are used to define `o2$` from `o2$`.

### You should be able to change implementation specifics you care

If you're given an Observable you cannot change you shouldn't be concerned with it's specific implementation but only with what it emits. In this case the Observable is a black box to you and as far as you know just emits `{ category: 2, name: 'Some2' }`. You don't know and shouldn't care about specific things the Observable did along the way to emit this value.

BUT you seem to know and care about what the Observable did before emitting this value. If you do, there has to be a way for you (or a colleague) to change the implementation of the Observable.

### Inject code dynamically

If you have code where one part should be fixed and another part should be dynamic you can define a higher order function (fixed part) that accepts another function (dynamic part) as input and create different Observables from one original Observable this way:

```ts
let getObjects$ = (predicate: (value: any) => boolean) => of([
  {
    category: 1,
    name: "Some1"
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    name: "Some2"
  }
]).pipe(map(o => o.filter(predicate)));

getObjects$(v => v.category === 1).subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
getObjects$(v => v.category === 2).subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that you cannot change the observable. The example you gave me will help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are applying pipe operator in the first operation (`objects$` => `Observable.pipe()`).
After first operation, `objects$` inner value will be:

```
[{category: 2,name: 'Some2'}]
```

Then your **second operation** will be done on the **result of first** one(`Observable.pipe(...).pipe(...)`). It will not change the value of `objects$`.
But you're again subscribing the initial observable (`objects$` => `Observable.pipe()`).
The second pipe will **not mutate the value**, instead returns **new `Observable`** after applying `pipe` operator function.

For the desired result:

```
let objects$ = of([
  {
    category: 1,
    name: "Some1"
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    name: "Some2"
  }
]);

objects$
  .pipe(map(o => o.filter(b => b.category === 1)))
  .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));

objects$
  .pipe(map(o => o.filter(b => b.category === 2)))
  .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is that I do not have control over the original observable i.e. the pipe is already there.

Comment: Happy to know that the issue is resolved! :)
But in the accepted answer, you're passing predicate to the pipe. If you have no control over the original `Observable` with `pipe(...)` already there, how you can pass the predicate into the `filter()` in `pipe()`?

Comment: The original observable needed a `pipe(map(filter()))`, but I thought you can dynamically change the `map()` in the pipe. So with the predicate I can keep the `map()` and only change the `filter()` criteria. :)